# Scaling the object makes it too big, can't seem to align with blueprints

Tags: scale

I'm following [this video tutorial for making a chair in Blender,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AP5CTAKckBI).

When I scale up my chair leg like at the end of the tutorial at 18:41 I can't seem to get it right like he does, my chair leg ends up being way too big when it finally fits and it won't fit in the other blueprint's I have.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nrGk.jpg

Comment: Try applying your scale with Windows+A or Cmd+A. Also please provide image references in your question.

Comment: I've added pictures you can compare with the video. Also, hitting windows+A only opens up some window outside the Blender program, so I'm not sure if that's right.